# How does Kubernetes invoke a Docker image?

Tags: docker, flask, kubernetes, uwsgi, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to run a Flask app via uWSGI in a Kubernetes deployment. When I run the Docker container locally, everything appears to be working fine. However, when I create the Kubernetes deployment on Google Kubernetes Engine, the deployment goes into Crashloop Backoff because uWSGI complains:

`uwsgi: unrecognized option '--http 127.0.0.1:8080'`.

The image definitely has the http option because:

    `a. uWSGI was installed via pip3 which includes the http plugin.
    b. When I run the deployment with --list-plugins, the http plugin is listed.
    c. The http option is recognized correctly when run locally.`

I am running the Docker image locally with:

`$: docker run <image_name> uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:8080`

The container Kubernetes YAML config is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: launch-service-example
  name: launch-service-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: launch-service-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: launch-service-example
          image: <image_name>
          command: ["uwsgi"]
          args:
            - "--http 127.0.0.1:8080"
            - "--module code.experimental.launch_service_example.__main__"
            - "--callable APP"
            - "--master"
            - "--processes=2"
            - "--enable-threads"
            - "--pyargv --test1=3--test2=abc--test3=true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: launch-service-example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: launch-service-example
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

The container is exactly the same which leads me to believe that the way the container is invoked by Kubernetes may be causing the issue. As a side note, I have tried passing all the args via a list of commands with no args which leads to the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because of the difference between arguments processing in the console and in the configuration.

To fix it, just split your args like that:

```
args:
  - "--http"
  - "127.0.0.1:8080"
  - "--module code.experimental.launch_service_example.__main__"
  - "--callable"
  - "APP"
  - "--master"
  - "--processes=2"
  - "--enable-threads"
  - "--pyargv"
  - "--test1=3--test2=abc--test3=true"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. I also subsequently realized that using an equals sign (aka. --http=127.0.0.1:8080) fixes the problem as well.